# Ubercart - different payment gateway settings per product

Tags: ubercart, payment-gateways

i want to be able to set one product as UC_CREDIT_AUTH_ONLY, meaning no charge will be made now. in the admin i can only change this setting globally, meaning that all my products will be charged UC_CREDIT_AUTH_ONLY. How can i get this to work only for one?

currently i'm using paypal website pro as gateway, but if i have to, i'll switch to athorize.net.

using drupal 6 + ubercart 2

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sandbox project for multiple gateways. I attempted to contact the developer a few days ago, but haven't heard back.

http://drupal.org/node/1106004

you select the profile in the product edit. Its not complete but close.